# What's the correct way to check if it's possible to perform a fast-forward merge with git merge-base?

Tags: git

I've created a bash script that performs the following tasks:

1. Fetch changes from upstream;
2. Check if a fast-forward merge is possible;
3. Merge `origin/master` into `master` if #2 is true;
4. Rebase `master` on top of `origin/master` if #2 is false

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

local_branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)
remote_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u})
remote=$(git config branch.$local_branch.remote)

echo "Fetching from $remote..."
git fetch $remote

if git merge-base --is-ancestor $local_branch $remote_branch; then
    echo 'Fast-forward is possible. Merging...'
    git merge --ff-only $remote_branch
else
    echo 'Fast-forward is not possible. Rebasing...'
    git rebase --preserve-merges $remote_branch
fi
```

I tested it a few times and it seems to work, but I'm not very confident about the `git merge-base` part. I know the theory behind a fast-forward merge, and it seems right to use `master` and `origin/master` as arguments to `merge-base`, but I'm no Git expert.

So I ask: is that the correct way to check if a fast-forward merge is possible just after a fetch is performed?

Comment: Why don't you just always rebase? Rebase will fast-forward if possible.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In my tests, performing a fast-forward merge has shown to be much quicker than rebasing, so I'd rather rebase only when a fast-forward merge isn't possible.

Comment: Why don't you always do git merge --ff-only and rebase only if that fails?

Comment: @nert That's indeed a valid option, but I'd like to know how to simply check if a FF is possible.

Answer (score 34):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <commit> <commit>
```

`--is-ancestor` Checks if the first `<commit>` is an ancestor of the second `<commit>`, and exit with status 0 if true, or with status 1 if not. Errors are signaled by a non-zero status that is not 1.

e.g.

```
 git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/master master
```

Comment: The OP wants to deal with two branches, not two commits. It would improve this answer if you could replace <commit> with a reference to the HEAD commit on each branch.

Comment: and the status code can be checked with `echo $?`, so an example command for manual checking could be `git merge-base --is-ancestor develop myotherbranch && echo $?`

Comment: To see status code in PowerShell on Windows, use `echo $lastExitCode` (learned from [dbsnet.fr](http://blog.dbsnet.fr/check-last-exit-code-with-powershell)). So, `git merge-base --is-ancestor branch1 branch2; echo $lastExitCode`.

Comment: @BobRay, you can put the branch name in place of `<commit>`, and git resolves it to the commit referred to by that branch's HEAD.

Comment: @lucidbrot I think `&&` won't work if the first command fails. So perhaps this would be slightly better: `git merge-base --is-ancestor develop myotherbranch; echo $?`

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the `--ff-only` option.

`git merge origin/master --ff-only`

If it is possible to fast-forward, it will happen automatically. If it is not possible the command will fail with `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.` and you can run a rebase command instead.

Comment: Does this mean it's a complete rollback? I'm writing a script where I've fetched the changes from upstream, then I've checked for uncommited changes of the tracked files, then I've checked if there's any untracked files. Now I want to see if any of the untracked files would be overriden. Dry-running the merge would be good enough, I think. I think that covers all my cases?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually perform the merge you will know for sure! Use a temporary branch so you won't mess anything up in your other branches.

```
git fetch
git checkout -b tmp_branch master
git merge origin/master
```

Your script needs to evaluate the merge result here, and either merge origin/master into master or not.

And just remove the temporary branch when it's not needed.

```
git branch -D tmp_branch
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It might work, but `merge-base` is more straightforward because it gives an instant answer just by computing the merge base between two commits.

Comment: I use the example above, but with  `git merge --ff-only origin/master`. It definitely works, and is much easier to remember than the merge-base command.

Answer (score 2):

A command to check if `$remote_branch` is an ancestor of `$local_branch` is:

```
test -z "$(git rev-list --max-count 1 $local_branch..$remote_branch)"
```

Without `--max-count 1` this lists all commits that are in `$remote_branch` but not `$local_branch`. As you're interested only in if there are such commits and throw away the output anyhow, you can add `--max-count 1` to speed things up a bit.